# Accuracy of series expansion for exponential, estimates for tail and minimum number of terms

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

I was thinking about the accuracy of the series expansion $e^x = \sum x^n/n!$ when taking a finite number of terms; if we take $n$ terms, the error is $\sum_{m>n}^{\infty} x^m/m!$ ("fractional error" $e^{-x}\sum_{m>n}^{\infty} x^m/m!$).

Suppose we are trying to estimate $e^x$ for large positive $x$, with some acceptable "fractional error" $\Delta$, where the "fractional error" for an estimate $v$ of $e^x$ is $(e^x - v) / e^x = 1 - v e^{-x}$ (note this will always be positive for us since we consider positive $x$ and estimate using the series). From Taylor's theorem we know that the fractional error is bounded by $x^{n+1}/(n+1)!$, so for a given $x$ and $\Delta$ we may find some $n$ such that $x^{n+1}/(n+1)! \le \Delta$.

The non-specific version of my question (but please see below) is given this initial $x$, $n$, and $\Delta$, how must $n$ grow with $x$ to maintain the same $\Delta$?

I have tried to answer this question myself but got stuck. It is not hard to show the following equality for the fractional error (one way is to note $dE/dx = e^{-x} x^n/n!$),

\begin{equation}
E(n,x) = e^{-x} \sum_{m > n}^{\infty} \frac{x^m}{m!} 
= \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^x e^{-t} t^n dt = \frac{\gamma(n+1,x)}{n!} = \frac{\gamma(n+1,x)}{\Gamma(n+1)}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

where $\gamma(n,x)$ is just shorthand for the integral but is also known as the "[lower incomplete Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)".

The more specific question is then how $E(f(x),x)$ behaves for different increasing functions $f$, for $x > 0, f(x) > 0$. I have made some small headway, but have been able to prove nothing. First, some contour plots:

[image: Plot of $E(n,x)$ for $n,x \in (0,100)$]
[image: Plot of $E(n,x)$ for $n,x \in (0,1000)$]

It is not hard to conjecture from these plots that for $f(x) = ax$, if $a > 1 + \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon \ge 0$, there is a drop-off asymptotically approaching zero, but I can't *prove* this (esp. what is $\epsilon$ and does the function approach 0 or some $\delta > 0$?). To further support this claim, $E(n,x)$ is the [CDF of the Gamma distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) with shape $n + 1$; there is an estimate for the median of the CDF (found on the same Wikipedia page) that is approximately linear with slope 1 (slightly lower than 1, in fact).

As an aside, although I would really like an answer to this form of the question, referring to the function $E(f(x),x)$, since I have spent some time on it and would like to know how to attack similar problems with these functions, please let me know if I am approaching this particular problem in an overly complicated way.